# How to test the app using Postman properly?

Tags: java, spring, testing, postman

I have a Java app based on Spring Boot and just started to use Postman and instead of testing a specific endpoint, now I want to check a changes that affect different aspect of assume that I added some endpoints for `Employee` endpoints for:

```
//GET
http://localhost:8080/api/v1/employee/getEmployees


//POST
http://localhost:8080/api/v1/employee/createEmployee


// PUT:
http://localhost:8080/api/v1/employee/updateEmployee/id


// DELETE:
http://localhost:8080/api/v1/employee/deleteEmployee/id
```

In this scene I added all the related methods for these endpoints to:

EmployeeController

EmployeeService

EmployeeRepository

There may also be some additional methods used by these CRUD methods in the Controller, Service and Repository as well.

**Note:** I already defined unit and integration tests, but just need to get info for Postman aspect with test data in the database.

In this scene:

**1.** Is sending the requests to the endpoints (Controller) enough for testing all of these EmployeeController, EmployeeService and EmployeeRepository? Or how should I test all of these methods that I added for Employee CRUD operations?

**2.** I think there is not another alternative to check the Service and Repository methods except from sending the requests via Controller? Is that true?

Comment: When testing, no matter what tools you use, the first step is to clearly specify exactly what each test is actually testing. For example, "when the user POSTs to endpoint `/api/v1/blah/blah/blah`, then the response should be...". Fill in the blanks and describe as many tests you need for each of your endpoints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When testing, no matter what tools you use, the first step is to clearly specify exactly what each test is actually testing. For example, "when the user POSTs to endpoint `/api/v1/employee/getEmployees`, then the response should be...". Fill in the blanks and describe as many tests you need for each of your endpoints.

Note how my example description only uses the path and says nothing about controllers, services, or repositories. From the point of view of a HTTP client such as Postman, only the path is important. The implementation details such as controllers, services, and repositories are completely invisible to Postman.

Side note: I suggest creating a single route `/api/v1/employee/` that allows both `GET` and `POST` requests. There is no need to name the route `/api/v1/employee/getEmployees` since that is what the `GET` verb means. Likewise, `POST` already means to create an employee, so there's no need to add `createEmployee` in the path. Similarly a path `/api/v1/employee/id/` can allow `GET` and `PUT` without needing the extra words in the path describing the action.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this good explanations. In this scene, I think I just need to test the endpoints in the Controller. Is that true?

Comment: @Rosa Yes, Postman can only see the routes/endpoints. It does not know anything of the Controller or underlying details. This will indirectly test the service and the repository, but from this point of view, you should NOT worry about those details. Only think in terms of what should happen when you call a specific endpoint.

Comment: What about testing `Service` and `Repository` methods? Is there any approach to test them **except from Unit and Integration Tests**?

Comment: @Rosa Postman knows nothing about the Java code that implements these endpoints. In fact, it doesn't even know that they are implemented with Java. They could just as easily be implemented wit Python, PHP, or any other language as far as Postman cares. Postman only knows how to make an HTTP request to a URL and receive back the response. So Postman cannot be used to test your service and repository directly. Tests with postman **are** integration tests. If you want to test service or repository methods directly, you will need to write those tests in Java.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you. But I just wanted to be clarified about that how can I test an endpoint with its related methods by using a test database. In this scene, I think testing an endpoint on Controller also meaning testing their related methods on Service and Repository. Of course it does not as proper as writing and running test, BUT I mean that when I call createEmployee method on Controller, it will also call their related method on Service (and of course some related sub methods on Service) and then it will also call the related method on Repository. As a result I could test these methods

Comment: @Rosa Yes, testing a route with Postman is an integration test. It will test all of the code that runs when you issue a request to the given route. When writing a test like this, it is important to think at the correct level of abstraction. Postman only deals with requests and responses. It does not "call" methods.

Comment: Many thanks for you wonderful explanations. Voted up and marked as answer.